# iOS: Change background image for all button when one of them is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the selected button from two buttons.

This is my scenario:

In my `ViewController`, I let the user to choice between 3 types (to select only one) through a button. At first, there is only one button displayed. When this button is tapped, I display the two others under it (one under the other like the picture. The only difference is that I don't display the selected button twice (not like the "Reply" in the picture)).

[image]

Let’s name the 3 buttons, btn1 (selected), btn2 and btn3 (those 2 last buttons are in a view which is shown only when btn1 is tapped, and hidden when a button of the 3 is tapped again). I describe by those buttons 3 types, type1, type2 and type3. Suppose that for the first time btn1 has as background image type1ImageOn.png (“on” which means “selected” ) and btn2 -> type2ImageOff.png and btn2 -> type3ImageOff.png. When the user select for example btn2, then the btn1 (selected) image has to be set from type1ImageOn.png to type2ImageOn.png, the btn2 -> type1ImageOff.png and btn3 -> type3ImageOff.png.

I have created a function in order to know what type is selected but I can't get it works:

```
-(void) checkSelectedFilterBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
 UIButton *tmpFilter = sender;
 UIImage* type1ImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type1ImageOff.png"];
 UIImage* type2ImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type2ImageOff.png"];
 UIImage* type3ImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type3ImageOff.png"];

 UIImage* type1ImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type1ImageOn.png"];
 UIImage* type2ImageOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type2ImageOn.png"];
 UIImage* type3ImageOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type3ImageOn.png"];


if (tmpFilter.currentBackgroundImage == type1ImageOff)
    {
        self.selectedFilter = @"type1";
        self.filterButton.imageView.image = type1ImageOn;
        self.filterBtn2.imageView.image = type2ImageOff;
        self.filterBtn3.imageView.image = type3ImageOff;
    }
    else if (tmpFilter.currentBackgroundImage == type2ImageOff) {

        self.selectedFilter = @"type2";
        self.filterButton.imageView.image = type2ImageOn;
        self.filterBtn2.imageView.image = type1ImageOff;
        self.filterBtn3.imageView.image = type3ImageOff;

    } else {

        self.selectedFilter = @"type3";
        self.filterButton.imageView.image = type3ImageOn;
        self.filterBtn2.imageView.image = type1ImageOff;
        self.filterBtn3.imageView.image = type2ImageOff;
    }

    self.filterView.hidden = true;
}
```

I call this function in the IBActions of btn2 and btn3 like this:

```
- (IBAction)filterBtn2TouchUp:(id)sender {

    [self checkSelectedFilterBtn:sender];

}

- (IBAction)filterBtn3TouchUp:(id)sender {

    [self checkSelectedFilterBtn:sender];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the `UIButton` background image like `button.imageview.image = image;`

You have to use setter method to set the background image of the `UIButton`.

**Example :**

```
[self.filterButton setBackgroundImage:type1ImageOn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.filterBtn2 setBackgroundImage:type1ImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.filterBtn3 setBackgroundImage:type2ImageOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thank you you're right about the way of setting the  background image for an `UIButton` but it seems that I have a problem with the tests for example : `tmpFilter.currentBackgroundImage == type1ImageOff` because when I debug the execution goes always to the last `else`. The name of the images are the same as what I have in my project and there values are not nil when I debug

Comment: You have to compare like this `if ([tmpFilter backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == type1ImageOff)`

Comment: I test it but I'm getting the same problem

Comment: are you setting background image or button image? setBackgroundImage or setImage?

Comment: I want to set the background button image

Comment: sorry.. use this `if ([[tmpFilter backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual: type1ImageOff])`

Comment: Is that normal that when I make the first test (I select a button for the first time) it goes directly to the else? Just after this first test when I change again the button it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147394/discussion-between-subramanian-and-llg).

Answer (score 0):

Please use setImage forState method in you UIButton

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"type1ImageOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"type1ImageOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

once myButton.enabled = YES it will present the selected state image and NO for normal state

Comment: Thank you  but it seems also that I have a problem with the tests for example : `tmpFilter.currentBackgroundImage == type1ImageOff` because when I debug the execution goes always to the last else. The name of the images are the same as what I have in my project and there values are not nil when I debug